# Adding Attribute to crispy forms django

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-crispy-forms

I am using bootstrap switch and it looks like if I want to add a label I need to:

```
<input name="switch-labelText" type="checkbox" data-label-text="Label">
```

I am using crispy forms and I can see that I can do add attribute using the Field like so:

```
Field('field_name', css_class="black-fields")
```

This all makes sense to me but I can't seem to add data-label-text. So my question is can I make a custom attribute with crispy forms?

Here is my form:

```
class InstanceCreationForm(forms.Form):
    some_field = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    some_field2 = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    some_field3 = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(InstanceCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_show_labels = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            #This is a syntax error
            Field('some_field', data-label-text="whatever")
        )
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [the docs](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/layouts.html#layout-objects-attributes):

> If you want to set html attributes, with words separated by hyphens like `data-name`, as Python doesn’t support hyphens in keyword arguments and hyphens are the usual notation in HTML, underscores will be translated into hyphens, so you would do:
>   `Field('field_name', data_name="whatever")`

So you need to use the keyword `data_label_text` instead.

```
Field('some_field', data_label_text="whatever")
```

Comment: Wow, I must have read that line like 20 times, I even looked at the source code and saw the find replace, so sorry thanks a lot for the help I'm so silly.

Answer (score 0):

From the source code.

```
    # We use kwargs as HTML attributes, turning data_id='test' into data-id='test'
    self.attrs.update(dict([(k.replace('_', '-'), conditional_escape(v)) for k, v in kwargs.items()]))
```

it puts all the kwargs to your form element, so you can do something like.

```
Field('YOUR_FIELD_NAME', data_label_text="Label")
```