# Passing the error value to the JS code in template. Django

Tags: django, forms

I have purchased one of the Bootstrap templates. I am trying to pass a value from a view or forms.py to my template

```
    <div class="input-group">
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="text" placeholder="Hi there, I would like to ..." aria-label="Hi there, I would like to ..." required
                data-msg="Please enter a reason."
                data-error-class="u-has-error"
                data-success-class="u-has-success"></textarea>
    </div>
```

Exactly this value `data-msg="Please enter a reason."`

How can I do this? pass the value to the JS code or is it possible? How to change the content of the message which will be displayed by the JS code.

Comment: You want to replace the string for data-msg? Why not use template variables to display the passed value?

Comment: How can I do it if my input field looks like this (in template)? `{{ form.example|as_crispy_field }}` I use something like that now:     `<div class="js-form-message mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">
        {{ form.example|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>`

Comment: Please check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31227692) helps.